# How can I "right click" with a USB mouse on Android 3.1?

Tags: usb, 3.1-honeycomb, mouse

I've got a Logitech USB mouse and keyboard plugged into my Xoom, which is running Tiamat 1.4.4 kernel on top of Android 3.1. Both are recognized and provide input correctly, but I noticed that the right mouse button is treated just as a left mouse button click. I had hoped that this would instead act like a long press since that's something of an analogue to the right click concept, but I can't find a way to do so. This is particularly annoying because I'm trying out Splashtop and it makes a lot of things really awkward or downright impossible.

Is there any setting (or other method) to make the right click button actually perform a "right click" type of action, such as a long press?

Comment: Can't you just long press with the mouse button?

Comment: @raybritton: Sure, but I still feel like I have a wasted mouse button, and it's of course slower than a legitimate right click. This also seems to cause some weirdness with certain functions. Plus, Splashtop likes to plug games as a feature, and I'd hate to play e.g. Half Life 2 without a true alt-fire mouse button (it's comfortable and already ingrained into my head, though I could remap to left shift or something).

Comment: I do agree, it would be useful, and I can't see a technical reason it couldn't be implemented.

Comment: Presumably the kernel handles this (correct me if I'm wrong) so you could make or request a kernel mod to do this.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately there is currently no way to get the right mouse button working as a right mouse button. Long press is the only way to do it. Sorry.

Comment: Any links to docs or source?

Answer (score 1):

middle mouse button does it for me!